# How to stop returning Decimal's objects in async_sessionmaker with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these code snippets to run queries on mysql but all the integers or floats numbers are returned as python Decimal() objects

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine(
    f"mysql+asyncmy://{_db_user}:{_db_passwd}@{_db_host}:{_db_port}/{_db_schema}",
    echo=False,
)

async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

async with async_session() as session:
   result = await session.execute(text(query))
   result = result.mappings().fetchall()
```

any idea's to stop returning Descimal's and start return the Db data type?

I can't use Model's or mapped classes because the tables are huge with so many columns and also it is a lot of different tables

I'm already crying here :/

sqlalchemy[asyncio]==2.0.16
asyncmy==0.2.8

Comment: If you're not using models, then what's the point of using sqlalchemy at all?  Why not just use the `mysql.connector` class directly?  That gives you direct access to the rows.

Comment: @TimRoberts because of all the mysql connectors I found that support async, none of them brought me the database lines in the python dict object, and sqlalchemy manages to do so when calling the mappings() method.

Is there any connector that can do the same thing that mappings does? I may not have seen :)

Comment: *none of them brought me the database lines* -- I don't know what that means.  `mysql.connector` comes from the MySQL team, and sqlalchemy uses it under the hood.  Perhaps you should show an example of your table and the results you get back.

Answer (score 0):

> stop returning Decimals and start return the Db data type?

Look carefully at your mysql schema. That *is* the DB data type.
Rather than IEEE-754 floats, you probably have fixed precision
scaled integers that keep some specified number of decimal digits.
This is quite common in a financial setting where people
don't want to see $.01 roundoff errors coming from binary repeated fractions.

Rather than issuing `SELECT *` you could specify all the column names,
and ask mysql to cast each value to integer or whatever you find convenient.

Or you could accept what comes back and transform it.
So

```
    for row in result:
        print(", ".join(map(str, row)))
```

becomes

```
    for row in result:
        print(", ".join(map(str, map(float, row))))
```

Write a short helper function if you find yourself frequently doing that.

Comment: I tried to use this approach, however the values ​​that are in the DB like 1345.98 for example, are like 0.0304 in the float or str of python. This is just a demonstration of the problem I'm facing, it's not exactly this transformation. In the end my calculations come out completely wrong in python :/

Comment: I heard you say that with `v = Decimal('1345.98')`, you find that `float(v) == .0304` and `str(v) == '0.0304'`. That stretches credulity. Please edit your question so it is an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), allowing SO contributors to copy-paste-execute and see what you see.